# deleting google maps without deleting gmail

Tags: gmail, google-maps

I mistakenly entered a google maps account on a shared gmail account. I don't want to delete the shared email account, but would like to change the google maps to my own gmail account and delete it from the shared one.

Answer (score 2):

If you used the shared account to create a personal map in www.google.com/mymaps, then you can simply export is to to a KML file, and then import it to a new myMaps file in your own account.   (You can also share it with your personal account from the shared one - but that won't remove it from the shared account.)